# FastAPI Async Def calling common function

Tags: fastapi

I want to wrap the upload part in a common function since it is used in multiple API routes, but how do I do it since it is using `async def` here.

```
@app.post("/api/od")
async def image_classification(files: typing.List[fastapi.UploadFile] = fastapi.File(...)):
    upload_path = pathlib.Path("upload")#.joinpath(token)
    upload_path.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
...

    return results
```

Comment: You can create [dependency](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/) for this common part

Comment: @alex_noname I saw common parameters in the link, can we create common function?

Comment: @alex_noname and also the common function requires some parameters, as I can see in `Depends` there is no way to pass in parameters

Comment: Depends on the parameters it needs. You can access the raw `Request` and access all the `HTTP` parameters. If it needs other parameters, then I don't know, since this scenario never occurred to me yet